# How can I return A and b from this exponential fit function?

Tags: c#, curve-fitting, numerical-methods, non-linear-regression, mathnet-numerics

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double;
using MathNet.Numerics.Optimization;

namespace NonLinearRegressionExample
{
    public class NonlinearRegressionCurveFitting
    {
        public static (List<double>, List<double>, List<double>) FitCurve(List<double> xData, List<double> yData)
        {
            // example data
            var xDataDense = new DenseVector(xData.ToArray());
            var yDataDense = new DenseVector(yData.ToArray());

            Vector<double> Model(Vector<double> parameters, Vector<double> x)
            {
                var y = CreateVector.Dense<double>(x.Count);
                for (int i = 0; i < x.Count; i++)
                {
                    y[i] = parameters[0] * Math.Exp(parameters[1] * x[i]);
                }
                return y;
            }

            var start = new DenseVector(new double[] { 1.0, 0.1 });
            var objective = ObjectiveFunction.NonlinearModel(Model, xDataDense, yDataDense);
            var solver = new LevenbergMarquardtMinimizer(maximumIterations: 10000);
            var result = solver.FindMinimum(objective, start);

            Vector<double> points = result.MinimizedValues;

            Vector<double> minimizing = result.MinimizingPoint;

            return (xData, new List<double>(points.ToArray()), new List<double>(minimizing.ToArray()));
        }
    }
}
```

**Driver program:**

```
var fittedCurve = NonlinearRegressionCurveFitting.FitCurve(xData, yData);

            List<double> points = fittedCurve.Item2;
            List<double> result = fittedCurve.Item3;

            ///Output the results
            if (result.Count == 2)
            {
                DataPlotter plotter = new DataPlotter();
                //plotter.ZoomXaxis(0, 10);
                plotter.AddCurve("original",
                    new List<double>(xData.ToArray()),
                    new List<double>(yData.ToArray()),
                    IsSymbolVisible: false, color: Color.Red);
                plotter.AddCurve("fitted",
                    new List<double>(xData.ToArray()),
                    new List<double>(points.ToArray()),
                    IsSymbolVisible: false,
                    color: Color.Green);
                plotter.AddPoint("Point", result[0], result[1], Color.BlueViolet);
                plotter.ShowDialog();
            }
```

The [above source code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77859051/159072) fits an exponential curve using nonlinear regression.

However, how can I return the best `A` and `b` values from this C# function for the exponential formula

```
y = A * exp(-x * b)
```

?

.

This function is returning `MinimizingPoint` which seems to be the starting point of the x-axis.

[image]

.

Comment: @Sinatr, That point is the starting point of the x-axis. I already wrote that in my OP. The point is purple-blue on the plot.

Comment: Check `result.ReasonForExit` value, what [value](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/master/src/Numerics/Optimization/ExitCondition.cs#L32) it has?

Comment: @Sinatr, `Reason for exit: RelativePoints`.

Comment: Good, so the result was [found](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/master/src/Numerics/Optimization/LevenbergMarquardtMinimizer.cs#L163) and then method [return 3 values](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/master/src/Numerics/Optimization/LevenbergMarquardtMinimizer.cs#L227), but only [IObjectiveModel](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/master/src/Numerics/Optimization/IObjectiveModel.cs) has chance to contain parameters (if they were somehow set by passing `P` and model together).

Comment: Try `objective.Point[0]` and `objective.Point[1]`, those should be `a` and `b`, hopefully the last (best) ones.

Comment: What are the exact values of `result[0]` and `result[1]`? If you look carefully at the purple-blue point, you will see that it is not exactly at the origin. Set a break-point and inspect the values.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, `(0.84275567216928349,  -0.0071155733183345549)`.

Comment: Okay, and what's wrong with these values? They mean `y = 0.84275567216928349 * exp(-0.0071155733183345549 * x)`. See [curve on WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+0.84275567216928349+*+exp%28-0.0071155733183345549+*+x%29+for+x+%3D+0+..+1000). Do not plot these values directly. Instead insert them into the formula to get the y-value for a given x value.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, Plz, post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values returned by `MinimizingPoint` are the parameters to the fitted function. In your case of `y = A * exp(b * x)`, the first parameter is `A = 0.84275567216928349` and the second is `b = -0.0071155733183345549`.

If you want to find a value for any given `x`, then calculate:

`y = A * exp(b * x)`

or with the concrete parameters:

`y = 0.84275567216928349 * exp(-0.0071155733183345549 * x)`

It makes no sense to plot these parameters given as `result[0]` and `result[1]` in the `FitCurve` method with

`plotter.AddPoint("Point", result[0], result[1], Color.BlueViolet);`

since they do not represent a point in the graph.